# NSMutableArray isn't adding my NSString

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Im trying to add a `NSString` to an `NSMutableArray` and then make the array into `NSData` and save it with `NSUserDefaults`. But the array is always nil.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

    NSData *data = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"GroupArray"];

    groups = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"%i", [groups count]);
}

-(IBAction)newFolder {
    if (textField.text != nil) {
        NSString *string = textField.text.capitalizedString;
        [library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:string
                    resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                        NSLog(@"Created a folder named: %@", group);
                    }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"An error occured! - %@", error);
                    }
         ];
        [groups addObject:string];
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:groups];
        [userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"GroupArray"];

        NSLog(@"%i", [groups count]);
    }
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:subView];
}
```

When the app starts i get a message in the console that the array is `NULL`. When I try to add the string the `NSLog(@"%i", [groups count]);` always return 0.

Why does this happen?

Comment: What does [userDefaults objectForKey:@"GroupArray"] contain ??

Comment: groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [userDefaults objectForKey:@"GroupArray"]]; if  [userDefaults objectForKey:@"GroupArray"] returns an Array

Comment: [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; dosen't really return an Array + groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and then groups = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; dosen't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
NSData *data = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"GroupArray"];
```

In this case, `data` will be `nil` when the code is executed for the first time, since there is yet no "GroupArray" property present.

```
groups = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

This causes `groups` be become `nil` as well, because calling `unarchiveObjectWithData:` with `nil` as an argument will return `nil` as well.

And because of all that, in `-newFolder`, `[groups addObject:string]` becomes `[nil addObject:string]`
Calling a method on `nil` is allowed in Objective-C, so you get no exception there. The return value of any method called on `nil` is, again, `nil` or `0`.

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:groups];
```

This causes `data` to be `nil` because groups is `nil`.

So you are always calling:

```
[userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"GroupArray"];
```

with `data = nil`

Quick fix:
Add `if (groups == nil) groups = [NSMutableArray array];` to the beginning of `-newFolder`

Answer (score 0):

In view didLoad method every time you are initialising new instance of **NSUserDefaults** and calling

> NSData *data = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"GroupArray"]; on the newly created object

which will return nil all the time because in the new instance there wont be any object for key @"GroupArray". Instead replace **userDefaults** with singleton object **[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]**

Modify your code as shown below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
     NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"GroupArray"];

     groups = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
     if (!groups)
     {
         groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
     }
     NSLog(@"group %@", groups);
     NSLog(@"%i", [groups count]);
}
```

Your newFolder method

```
  -(IBAction)newFolder 
  {
     if (textField.text != nil) 
     {
          NSString *string = textField.text.capitalizedString;
         [library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:string
                     resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                         NSLog(@"Created a folder named: %@", group);
                     }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"An error occured! - %@", error);
                     }
          ];
        [groups addObject:string];
         NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:groups];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"GroupArray"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

         NSLog(@"%i", [groups count]);
     }
     [self.view sendSubviewToBack:subView];
 }
```

This should work. As it worked for me.